# Adjective describing the increase of a value achieved by forfeit/default of another party/value

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm very interested in all things related to energy production and its future.

I'm looking for an adjective that would describe the return of the USA as the world 1st oil producer, not because of much increased US oil production, but rather because the current world oil production leader, Saudi Arabia, saw its output greatly decrease.

In the same vein I'm trying to convey the idea the US power production could indeed reach 50% of renewable energy soon, but mostly because the overall fossile fuel power production could fall and renewables would increase in proportion while not increasing in number (think about a salesman getting a  meagerly increased fixed income & a greatly reduced bonus).

> A _________ ["Forfeitful"/ Defaulting / Profiteering / Ptoseic (greek
>   Ptosi: Fall/Decrease) / proportional /
>   Decrementing / Demoting / Decreaseful / "Princeps Minutus"] rise?

I'll be grateful for any answer or suggestion you might have.

Comment: Unless you’d be happy with *A default increase…* could you suggest a sentence?

Did you notice *its future* is included in *all things related…*?

Is *world 1st oil producer* an attempt to make clear this is about quantity, not history?
British and I’d have thought US English would prefer *world’s premier/leading/foremost…*
Unless you really mean it, how does *much* help *increased US oil production*? Won’t *Saudi Arabia saw its output decrease* suffice?
What does *world oil production* contribute to *current  leader, Saudi Arabia*?
More…

Comment: Meanwhile *power production could… reach 50%…* is intelligible through context and guesswork, not wording.
*mostly because the overall fossile fuel power production could fall and renewables would increase in proportion while not increasing in number* does you no favours.
Arithmetically, I don’t understand the salesman analogy. Fixed salary and increased bonus, perhaps…
Idiomatically, *I’ll be grateful…* should be *I’d…*

Answer (score 1):

> **Relative**
> [rel-uh-tiv]
>
> /noun
>
> 2. something having, or standing in, some relation or connection to something else.
>
> /adjective
>
> 5. considered in relation to something else; comparative.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/relative)

"By sustaining the production speed, America will experience a ***relative*** rise in the global oil production, producing a larger percentage as the world produces less total oil."